# How can i create a reactive xml object in Vue 3?

Tags: xml, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, reactive

In Vue 2 it was easy to create a reactive xml object. So i could render a tree html view that was based on an xml object. Any change in the xml object triggered a view change and reflected the current state of the xml.

In Vue 3 this does not work any more.

So my question is:
What would be the best way to achieve the old vue 2 reactivity behavour for xml objects in Vue 3?

Edit:
For those who don't like the term "xml object", just replace it by  "XMLDocument".
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLDocument

Edit(2):
The purpose is to dynamically render a hierarchy of componentes where each component has a corresponding xml node. In other words: the xml defines the structure of the components. This must happen in a reactive way. So any change in the xml must re-render the corresponding component. This worked great and out-of-the-box in Vue2.
In Vue3 this seems not to work any more. My current approach is to have a MutationsObserver implemented in each component that listens to changes in "it's" xml node. But to have a more generic way would be great.

Comment: Please share the code

Comment: There is no such thing as "xml object"

Comment: Please show your code. Vue 3 is just as able to work with reactive Objects, as Vue 2 does.

Comment: Just take this example:

const xml = reactive(new DOMParser().parseFromString('<test id="d"><a tt="x">2</a></test>', 'application/xml'));

You won't see any reactive side effects in view or a any watcher if you change an attribute text node or append / remove more child nodes.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options:

1. Make the XML object a reactive string.  Then use a computed property to parse the string and create your DOM.  Then use the computed DOM to render your component.
2. Use a `shallowRef` for your DOM.  Then call `triggerRef` manually when you mutate your DOM.